# Как лучше сверстать на flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Изучаю flexbox, в шапке есть 2 блока, один блок надо прижать влево, а другой вправо и между пунктами что бы были отступы, я это сделал, годится ли этот код, как сделать лучше?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title></title>
  <style>
   ul {
   list-style: none;  
   border: 1px solid;          
   }
   header {
   border: 1px solid;
   }
   header {
   display: flex;
   }
   .left-block ul, .right-block ul {
   display: flex;
   }
   .left-block {
   order: 1;        
   }
   .right-block {
   order: 2;  
   margin-left: auto;      
   }
   .left-block li, .right-block li {
   margin-right: 10px;        
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="left-block">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="right-block">
    <ul>
     <li><span>Текст</span></li>
     <li><button>Войти</button></li>
     <li><a href="">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Зачем Вы задаёте блокам последовательность через `order`? Они ведь и так у Вас идут в нужном порядке. Это лишний ненужный код.

2) Не обязательно теги списков обрамлять в еще один `<div>`

---

> *один блок надо прижать влево, а другой вправо и между пунктами что бы были отступы, я это сделал, годится ли этот код, как сделать лучше?*

Выбранный метод подходит. Есть еще один - задать родителю `justify-content: space-beetween;`. Но особой разницы нет.